# How to set ionic defaults to android with $ionicConfigProvider

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to default my ionic settings to "android" instead of "ios" globally. What would be the easiest way? Do I have to set each setting seperately with $ionicConfigProvider or is there any basic function available?

For example this defaults `ion-spinner` to `android` explicitely:

```
$ionicConfigProvider.platform.default.spinner.icon( "android" );
```

I am wondering, if there is any basic function to set all platform stylings, directives,… to `android` defaults.